# How to set zeroDateTimeBehavior on JNDI DataSource without using URL?

Tags: tomcat, properties, datasource, jndi

In [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229839/how-to-create-data-source-without-pooling-in-tomcat) the poster implies that you can set `zeroDateTimeBehavior="convertToNull"` as an attribute on the `<Resource>` tag.

Does anyone know if this should be possible? All the docs I've looked at say that you can only add this property on the database connection url.

I'm actually looking for a way to set this property on the DataSource from within the Spring context, so that we don't have to go around and update all our various environments, or risk losing property this should someone need to change the connection url.

A Spring configured DataSource makes it very easy:

```
<bean id="propsDataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
  <property name="url" value="${connection.url}"/>
  <property name="user" value="${connection.username}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${connection.password}"/>
  <property name="zeroDateTimeBehavior" value="convertToNull"/>
 </bean>
```

Does anyone know how to do this through a JNDI configured DataSource?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Hello the same answer of JoseK

But i have to put it in this way:

```
<Resource 
    name="jdbc/TamaJNDI"
    auth="Container" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    maxActive="15" 
    maxIdle="3" 
    name="jdbc/TamaJNDI" 
    password="*******" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OBRAS_CONTROL?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" 
    username="TAMAWEB"/>
```

In my Tomcat context.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

The docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html state it should be passed on the URL.

Can you try if this works for you?

```
<ResourceParams name="jdbc/DataSourceName">
                    <parameter>
                         <name>zeroDateTimeBehavior</name>
                         <value>convertToNull</value>
                     </parameter>
</ResourceParams>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody needs this because they use

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=someProject:someRegion:someInstance
```

and have no URL to slap `zeroDateTimeBehavior` onto, use:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=someProject:someRegion:someInstance&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

This works because internally that parameter gets appended after

```
jdbc:mysql://google/somaDatabase?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=
```

hence the desired result:

```
jdbc:mysql://google/somaDatabase?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=someProject:someRegion:someInstance&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inside jndi resource

connectionProperties="zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<Resource 
name="jdbc/TamaJNDI"
auth="Container" 
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
maxActive="15" 
maxIdle="3" 
name="jdbc/TamaJNDI" 
password="*******" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OBRAS_CONTROL 
username="TAMAWEB"
connectionProperties="zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).